# Loading and manipulating a large size html file in IE 9

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-9

I'm loading **500kb to 900kb** of HTML file in IE 9. Applying CSS transform to the page to change the zoom size and re-positioning the page in my custom application. I've noticed that the bigger the file, the slower it performs.

In other browsers it performs fine and ok. Is there any way I can optimize and speed up the CSS transform manipulation for IE 9?

Here's the HTML file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/m22ex5r39blqguu/stocks.html

Comment: could you show us some code?

Comment: @KeesSonnema: What?  All 500 to 900K?!  ;o)

Comment: your html and css file.

Comment: at least the part which works in other browsers but not in chrome. we don't need your whole code.

Comment: Post the portion that isn't working in a jsfiddle or jsbin and we can take a look at it for you.

Comment: @Kiz: it's working but it's slower. Based on my observation, the bigger the file the slower it gets. I'll posting the HTML & CSS links.

Comment: Here's the HTML file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/m22ex5r39blqguu/stocks.html Any ideas on how to improve the performance of large file size HTML files?